# Web API method only allow post

Tags: c#, api, rest, model-view-controller

On the web api template provided by Microsoft, there are a bunch of methods in the `AccountController`.

Take for example `Logout`, it only allows POST requests and it warns if you try to do a GET to it.

```
// POST api/Account/Logout
[Route("Logout")]
public IHttpActionResult Logout()
{
    Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    return Ok();
}
```

Where is it defined that this only responds to a POST, or what is telling this to only respond to a POST?

It does not have an `HttpPost` attribute or anything on it.

Comment: It's not. At least not in the code that you posted.

Comment: Create a new project, VS2015 using .NET 4.5.2, web api, then try to do /api/account/logout, you get: 

<Error>
<Message>
The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.
</Message>
</Error>

Comment: Well, it's probably in the routes table inherited from the framework. You know, most of the framework comes to you compiled as dll's.

Comment: If .Net is unable to identify the verb, HttpPost is the default fallback.